# How to sort QTableView in Qt4 and up

Tags: python, qt, model, pyqt, qabstracttablemodel

[image]

Code creates a single `QTableView`. The column sorting was enabled.
When I click the column name (1,2 or 3 nothing happens).
How to make this sorting work without using proxy model?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class Model(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.items = [[1, 'one', 'ONE'], [2, 'two', 'TWO'], [3, 'three', 'THREE']]

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 3 
    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 3

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid(): return 

        if role in [QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, QtCore.Qt.EditRole]:
            return self.items[index.row()][index.column()]

def onClick(index):
    tableView.openPersistentEditor(tableView.model().index(index.row(), index.column()))
    print 'clicked index:  %s'%index

tableModel=Model()
tableView=QtGui.QTableView() 
tableView.setModel(tableModel)
tableView.clicked.connect(onClick)
tableView.setSortingEnabled(True)

tableView.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a proxy model? QSortFilterProxyModel is the way to go.

Comment: I found `QSortFilterProxyModel` complicates things quite noticeably since it remaps the sourceModel indexes. It becomes difficult to track the data especially if the delegates are used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a python developer, but it seems that there is no `sort()` method implemented in your model.

In C++, when you derive your custom model from the `QAbstractItemModel` (or `QAbstractTableModel`) you have to implement the `QAbstractItemModel::sort()` method in order to enable sorting.

Answer (score 3):

Although @alphanumeric doesn't want to use a ProxyModel, maybe someone else does, since it requires only 2 additional lines of code:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class Model(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.items = [[1, 'one', 'ONE'], [2, 'two', 'TWO'], [3, 'three', 'THREE']]

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 3
    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 3

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid(): return

        if role in [QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, QtCore.Qt.EditRole]:
            return self.items[index.row()][index.column()]


tableModel=Model()
tableView=QtGui.QTableView()

proxyModel = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel()
proxyModel.setSourceModel(tableModel)

tableView.setModel(proxyModel)
tableView.setSortingEnabled(True)

tableView.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score -3):

Thanks Tomas for the direction!

Below is the working solution in PyQt:

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class Model(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.items = [[1, 'one', 'ONE'], [2, 'two', 'TWO'], [3, 'three', 'THREE']]

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 3 
    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 3

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid(): return 

        if role in [QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, QtCore.Qt.EditRole]:
            return self.items[index.row()][index.column()]

    def sort(self, column=None, direction=None):
        print 'Model.sort: column: %s, direction: %s'%(column, direction)


tableModel=Model()
tableView=QtGui.QTableView() 
tableView.setModel(tableModel)
tableView.setSortingEnabled(True)

tableView.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: this does no sorting at all